# Some sites do not allow requesting the same file twice (IDM)

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, web, httpresponse

**Some sites do not allow requesting the same file twice** :

[image]

I face the previous error when i try to download my pdf in `button click event`:

---

```
 private void AddReportToResponse(LocalReport report )
        {
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string extension;
            string[] streams = new string[100];
            Warning[] warnings = new Warning[100];
            Response.Clear();
            byte[] pdfStream = report.Render("PDF", "", out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streams, out warnings);

            Response.ContentType = mimeType;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Application." + extension);
            Response.BinaryWrite(pdfStream);
            Response.End();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed my problem .

The problem was concerning Ajax :

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
                        <AjaxSettings>
                            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rbtn_generate">
                                <UpdatedControls>
                                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="GV_Shift_employees" />
                            </UpdatedControls>
                        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement resume download functionality for asp.net:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Implement-resume-in-aspnet-c1bbde36

Another option is to host the PDF file if you have static report files (for an acceptable time temporarily) and redirect to the same (make sure to use the same file name each time). That way the URL for pdf will remain the same and would support resume download.